# Consulta acerca del uso del protocolo ARP en los Hub(Concentradores)

Tags: redes

Bueno gente mi duda es:

- si en una red de área local que cuenta con hubs en lugar de switches(Ej una conexión entre 2 hubs y a cada uno de ellos dos PCS conectadas). ¿Es necesario el uso del protocolo ARP para efectuar broadcast y conocer la dirección MAC de algún PC en especifico?
- y también el uso de ARP Gratuitos para verificar si un dispositivo quiere asignarse una IP ya asignada a un dispositivo?

Ya que he leído información que ARP es un protocolo de nivel superior al nivel de enlace pero que este trabaja con dispositivos de nivel de la capa de enlace, y según un hub es de nivel físico caso contrario con un switch que es de nivel 2, espero puedan ayudarme a resolver esta duda, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Te resumo en puntos la respuesta a tus preguntas:

- ARP siempre será necesario, el transporte en la [capa2](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capa_de_enlace_de_datos) ( entre switches y /o tarjetas de red) se identifica con dirección `MAC`. Es después, cuando la tarjeta lo entrega en el sistema que entran en juego las `IPs`.
- En caso de especificarlas manualmente, no hará falta lanzar peticiones ARP en broadcast, pero deberás entrar manualmente en todos los dispositivos y no equivocarte en el proceso.
- Busca software con las palabras llave `ARP Monitor`, `ARP Watch`...
- Referente a la mención de `hub` y `switch`. En un `hub` no vas a poder introducir las direcciones `MAC` manualmente. En ese dispositivos no hay optimización de tránsito, cuando llegue un paquete lo va a enviar a todos los puertos. Esa es la gran diferencia entre un `switch` i un `hub`. El switch memoriza la ubicación de las `MACs` y puertos, para una mejor optimización del tránsito.